# No CSS or Razor Intellisense in .cshtml using VS 2013.2 Express for Web

Tags: visual-studio, razor, intellisense

There's a lot of posts from people who are having problems with Intellisense not working in .cshtml files. I'm having the same problem and even in .html files. With Bootstrap installed I don't get Intellisense even for class attributes.

As someone who is new to MVC, Razor and Bootstrap I can't tell you how much this hinders my progress in learning. It's very frustrating to be forced to Google for examples of syntax for virtually every piece of code I write.

I have tried most of the solutions I've read about, although some of them make me nervous to attempt - I'm currently in the middle of a project and just can't afford downtime if VS or something else would break, but I did uninstall VS 2013.2 Express for Web and reinstall it. I've tried running /resetsettings and went into Tools -> Options to make sure Intellisense was even enabled.

On this PC I have VS2010 Express for Web (maybe it's Visual Web Developer..., also have VS 2012 Express for Web and VS 2013.2 Express for Web.

I believe I also have Visual Studio 2013 Express installed.

I've uninstalled most of my NuGet packages and reinstalled.

I've rebooted my PC.

Tried creating a new Web Application project.

Totally uninstalled and reinstalled VS 2013.2 Express for Web.

I've loaded up VS 2012 Express for Web and created a new MVC project in it - still, no Intellisense in .cshtml.

This is a horrible problem to have. Does anyone have any other suggestions? For what it's worth, I do seem to get jQuery/Javascript and HTML Intellisense in .cshtml files. :S